# Get nested class type from string Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get a nested class type from a string dynamically.

```
           Class<Material> innerClass;
           try {
                innerClass = (Class<Material>)Class.forName("net.minecraft.world.level.material.Material$" + materialString);
                String registryName = bl.name.replaceAll("\\s+", "_").toLowerCase(); // make registry name lower_case
                list.add(registerBlock(registryName,
                        () -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(innerClass))));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Material has nested classes defined as:

```
    public final class Material {
    public static final Material AIR;
    public static final Material STRUCTURAL_AIR;
    public static final Material PORTAL;
    public static final Material CLOTH_DECORATION;
    public static final Material METAL;
    etc
    }
```

If `materialString` is "METAL" I'd like to be able to set innerClass equal to `Material.METAL`

As it stands I'm getting that a `Material` is required (BlockBehavior.Properties.of() expects a Material) while I'm providing a `Class<Material>`

Comment: *If my string is "METAL"*... What string?

Comment: Why don't you use an enum?

Comment: @shmosel updated to call the string materialString

Comment: The Material class is provided by a third party, I cannot change it.

Comment: `Class.forName("net.minecraft.world.level.material.Material").getDeclaredField(materialString).get(null)`

Comment: Thanks @shmosel that worked. Can you provide insight into what `get(null)` is doing here?

Comment: Did you check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#:~:text=If%20the%20underlying%20field%20is%20a%20static%20field%2C%20the%20obj%20argument%20is%20ignored%3B%20it%20may%20be%20null.)?

Comment: Those aren't nested classes, they are static fields.

Answer (score 0):

`getClass` gets.. a class. Hence the name. You don't want a class, you want to resolve a field. The right method is `getField`. You need to invoke it on the class that contains the field, so let's do that:

```
Field f = Material.class.getField("AIR");
```

`Material.class` is somewhat exotic java that means: The class object for the `Material` class (note that there is a comment that shows `Class.forName("....Material")` - this is slow, wordy, easily mistyped, and just bad all around, don't do that.

Now you have a instance of `java.lang.reflect.Field`. You can use the `.get()` method to read the value of this field. Normally, for a field, you'd need to write something like: `someInstanceOfAThing.fieldName`, and thus there is effectively a 'parameter' here: `someInstanceOfAThing`. However, for static fields, no instance is needed. Nevertheless, there is just the `.get(Object obj)` method. For static fields, the argument is ignored entirely, so we can just pass `null`:

```java
Material mat = (Material) Material.class.getField("AIR").get(null);
```

For what its worth, this is really bad java code. You'd use an enum for this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I said above the `Material` class is provided by a third party, I cannot change it.